# Could not find a declaration file for module - React Native

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I tried to install this package: https://github.com/hossamnasser938/api-request-biolerplate-actions .
I got this error:

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'api-request-biolerplate-actions'. '/Users/saeedmatar/Mikha4/node_modules/api-request-biolerplate-actions/lib/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm i --save-dev @types/api-request-biolerplate-actions` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'api-request-biolerplate-actions';`ts(7016)
```

The package doesn't have @types so i created d.ts file in the root of my project and entered:

```
declare module 'api-request-biolerplate-actions';
```

but I still get the same error.

I must mention that I have no tsconfig.json in my project because when I created my project, react didn't create it.

any help?

Comment: what is the name of the file you add `declare module 'api-request-biolerplate-actions';`

Comment: thanks for your comment: alltypes.d.ts

Comment: @aheze any suggestions?

Comment: @MikhaMatta sorry, I haven't used React Native at all. All I know about it is that it's called React Native and not Read Native :)